# Portable screencast recorder for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, screen-recording, portable

Can anyone recommend a portable screencast recorder for Windows?

**Requirements**

1. Portable
2. Works on Windows 7
3. High enough definition to have all recorded text legible
4. Record only a specified area of the screen
5. Gratis (freeware)

**Preferences (none required)**

6. Open-source
7. Also able to record the entire screen
8. Export to a variety of media formats (mpg, avi, gif)
9. Ability to extract specific frames

**Not Needed**

10. Ability to record high-speed video games

Comment: https://obsproject.com obs, but it denies no 1. Why it should be portable?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo Good question.  With few exceptions, I only use portable software.  Too many times software with installers will cause issues that are time-consuming to diagnose.  Most of the time, installers are not coded well enough to completely remove everything during uninstall.  Portable software is easy to manage and does not modify the system beyond its installation folder.

Answer (score 3):

> [Easy Screencast Recorder](https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/esr/) is a program to easily record short
>   videos of your desktop, that you can share with others.
>
> It can be run portably, and can record audio and video using any
>   installed codecs (including webm). Easily record entire screen,
>   multimon workspace, or specific region.

https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/esr/

Comment: Interesting, but it is not really "batteries-included", since it requests to install third-party encoding plugins (for example, choosing WebM did not work for me, nor MP4, still I have some codecs installed on computer).

Answer (score 1):

I use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/downloads.html) which is very handy. (Not perfect though, that's why I'm interested for other answers).

It is now open-source: https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif/

[image]

---

Another free option is [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) (Open Broadcaster 
Software).

A last software I've tried is Camtasia but it's not free.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What do you not like about it?

Comment: Minor UI details, but I'll study it more precisely to see if we can customise it in the Preferences window.

Comment: I'm the developer. You can contact me if there are any issues.